# PHP - Array and Div?

Tags: php, html

How can I make `.$i.` the div id -- depending on its value?

When I check the source, the div id is always `ImgDiv- 0`, how can I make it 1,2,3 ?

By the way, this code generates 3 divs. This is only part of the code. The printf is at the end, I just need this chunk edited.

If you need the rest of the code, I'll be happy to post it

None of those solutions worked :( Maybe if I post the full code?

```
<?php
$max = 3;
for ($i=0; $i<= $max; $i++) {
define('RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2',3);
define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2', '<div id="imgDiv-' .$i. '"style="width:170px;height:auto;float:left;text-align:center;top"><img src="%s" style="border-style:solid;border-width:2px;   border-color:black;"/><a href="%s" alt="%s" title2="%s">%s</a></div>');
}
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$images = array (
array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic2.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello' ),
array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic7.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ),
array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic9.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ), 
array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic5.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ),     
array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic3.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello3' )
);

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if ( count($images) < RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2 ) {
trigger_error('Not enough images given', E_USER_WARNING);
exit;
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

for ($i = 0; $i < RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2; $i++) {
shuffle($images);

$tmp = array_shift($images);
printf( RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2, $tmp['src2'], $tmp['href2'], $tmp['title2'], $tmp['title2'],$tmp['text2'] );    }
?>
```

Comment: Your for loop is incomplete (and probably will throw a parser error)

Comment: Regarding the for loop, proper syntax is: `for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: are you using an IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem might be in the fact that you're not using the for loop correctly.

For loops have the following syntax:

```
for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
    statement
```

where

- `expr1` is executed inconditionally before the loop.
- `expr2` is evaluated before iteration and the statement is executed if the evaluation renders `true`.
- `expr2` is executed at the end of each loop.

Therefore, try

```
<?php
$max = 3;
for ($i=0; $i<= $max; $i++) {
    define('RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2',3);
    define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2', '<div id="imgDiv-' .$i. '"style="width:170px;height:auto;float:left;text-align:center;top"><img src="%s" style="border-style:solid;border-width:2px;   border-color:black;"/><a href="%s" alt="%s" title2="%s">%s</a></div>');
}
?>
```

If you know the amount of divs that should appear, just take out the `$max` and use a fix number :)

EDIT: Further info in for loops: [Control Structures - php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Comment: Just changed a bit of code which was incorrect. Thanks showdev.